# Error: Closure containing a declaration cannot be used with result builder 'ViewBuilder'

Tags: mobile, new-operator, playgrounds

Good evening,
Getting an error on one line of code. New to this so is probably a simple human error.

**Error:**
Closure containing a declaration cannot be used with result builder 'ViewBuilder'

Image for the error is attached. Thank you in advance!